# Impossible to cross site ajax api calls in a chrome extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that calls my rails app's api. currently the api returns json and it works fine, however when I try to build it into a chrome extension, it says :

> Refused to load script from 'http://mysite.com/demo?q=hello?callback=jQuery16409466155741829425_1342489669670&_=1342489677171' because of Content-Security-Policy.

I looked up the document http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html and it sounds like I can't do this unless I implement my site into a https version. (under "Relaxing the default policy" section) I am not sure if I understood correctly and it feels ridiculous to make such a big change just because of this. Am I misunderstood? Or is there a workaround to this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In a Chrome extension, cross-site XMLHttpRequests are allowed, **provided that** you define the source in the manifest file - see http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html.

A JSONP implementation loads an external script using the `<script>` tag, and inserts it in the document. Unless the source is whitelisted through the [`"content_security_policy"`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H2-3) entry, JSONP cannot be used when [manifest version](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifestVersion.html) 2 is active (do **not** use manifest v1 to overcome this, because it's deprecated, and a suitable alternative already exist).

When you're unable to receive a JSON response instead of JSONP, use an ordinary request to fetch the data, cut off the callback, then parse it. Eg:

```js
// response is the response from the server
// Received through `XMLHttpRequest`, jQuery.ajax, or whatever you used
// cuts of jQuery....(  and the trailing )
response = response.replace(/^[^(]*\(/, '').replace(/\);?$/, '');
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842954/get-json-in-chrome-plugin/11845618#11845618 (especially if you're using jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

By default browsers do not allow this because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

However you can get around this by making a [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) request.

As you using jquery this super easy with [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think i need to clarify my question. I am already using jsonp and that's why it's working from a web page based call. However when I try to take it to chrome extension it doesn't work...

Comment: Just becuase you are returning JSON, doesnt mean you are doing a JSON-P request. Post some code.