# Sending Post Request from Chrome Extension (Origin?)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Hi I'm generating a POST XMLHTTPRequest to a remote server, but it's rejecting the post request. With a quick diff, I realize that the origin header of the XMLHTTPRequest from the XMLHTTPRequest I made has origin of chrome-extension://blahblahblahblahablahblah instead of the browser's url as origin. Is there a way to issue the request from the correct origin through chrome extension? Thanks!

Comment: Se the correct permissions in the manifest file, and you don't have to worry about CORS headers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Impossible to cross site ajax api calls in a chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515031/impossible-to-cross-site-ajax-api-calls-in-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: @RobW Hmm, the problem is a 400 bad request, instead of an error outright. I've already set the permission to allow the site's url, or is there somethign different that needs to be set for POST?

Comment: 400 Bad request indicates that you were actually able to send the request, but the server did not understand it. Double-check whether your request matches the format expected by the server.

Comment: @RobW Yea I thought the request went through too, but thought that maybe the server rejected it as 400 bad request due to incorrect origin?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try sending request using Content Scripts(to overcome domain issues)?

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot change the headers of the server, the only way to request it is to use jsonp. You can find more information about this here: [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: In a Chrome extension, JSONP is almost always a bad solution. It fails to work in Content scripts because of the different script execution context; In background/popup/options/.. pages, it fails because of the Content Security Policy.